# Jquery how do i remove and add a class after button click with time delay before other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a script for a button click for the following html which in turn brings up some content marked by "target-data"

the a tag .....

```
<a class='slide' href='#' data-url='who-are-musability-music-therapy.html' data-target='#music'>
          <span class='element'>Music</span>
         </a>
```

the data target that gets loaded...

```
<div id ="overview" class="animated bounceInUp"></div>
```

and the jquery that performs the on click ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($("#tam-content").load($(this).data("url") + ' ' + $(this).data("target")));

  });
});
```

QUESTION :- How do i put a timer in the script for 2 sec so that it removes the class bounceinup and adds bounceoutup then goes to the link as normal ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use `jQueryElement.toggleClass()` with a `jQueryElement.each()` loop?

Comment: i think so my jquery is a bit thin  but simply put , script as above  go to link but when clicked change the class and wait 2 seconds (so it can run) then go to the link .

Comment: perhaps even simpler i want to change the script to put in a timer and a removeclass add class for the bouceinup and bounceoutup

Comment: I'm guessing you don't need to use `setTimeout` as long as you toggle the class before running your other code. Code you want to run multiple times should generally be put into a function for reuse.

Comment: the class that i am replacing is a tiny transition effect that will need about 2 seconds to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, but maybe this is something you are looking for:

```
$(function(){
  $('.slide').click(function(){
    var t = $(this), tc = $('#tam-content');
    tc.load(t.data('url')+' '+t.data('target'), function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        var a = tc.find('.animated');
        if(a.hasClass('bounceInUp')){
          a.removeClass('bounceInUp').addClass('bounceOutUp');
        }
        else if(a.hasClass('bounceOutUp')){
          a.removeClass('bounceOutUp').addClass('bounceInUp');
        }
        // run other code here
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
});
```